# Why this code crashes the JVM?

Tags: java, jndi, java-6, jvm-crash

Why does this code crashes the JVM?

```
public Connection createConnectionFromDS() throws Exception {
    try {
        Connection con = null;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "my_ip");
        Context ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        log.debug("Looking up datasource " + dataSourceName);
        DataSource dataSource = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup(dataSourceName);
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        return con;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        throw new Exception("Datasource [" + dataSourceName + "] not bound!");
    }
}
```

The log is the following:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000001800060ba, pid=3816, tid=3076
#
# JRE version: 6.0_39-b04
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.14-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [db2jcct2.dll+0x60ba]
```

I have already upgraded from 6.0_29 to 6.0_39, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Briefly, it *shouldn't*. That looks like a bug in `db2jcct2.dll` (your DB2 driver).

```
# Problematic frame:
# C  [db2jcct2.dll+0x60ba]
```

Can you try another version of your JDBC driver ? And/or report this to IBM ?

Comment: I thought at first it was your JVM, but upon rereading I think it's your DB2 driver. Apologies for the confusion.